# Understanding compact sequences in $H^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm having trouble with the definition of (pre)compact sequences in the space $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ understood as the dual space of the Sobolev space $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$, and $\Omega$ a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Say we have a sequence $\{ f_n \}$ in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$, so continuous linear functions $f_n : W_0^{1,2}(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$, I have two questions.

1. I've found in Evans PDE the definition of a precompact sequence as

> A sequence is precompact if it has a convergent subsequence.

Just like when we are talking about precompact and compact sets is there a notion for compact sequences? If so, which is the difference? I've found the term in some papers/texts (about compensated compactness) but I don't know if they are talking about the same thing as Evans.

2. Say we have a condition like this

$$
\left| f_n(\phi) \right| \leq C_n \| \phi \|_{W_0^{1,2}},
$$

for every $\phi \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ where $C_n \to 0$ and doesn't depend on $\phi$, does this imply that the sequence is (pre)compact? If so, why?

Edit: What if we just had $\left| f_n(\phi) \right| \to 0$ instead?

Comment: I would think that if $\|f_n\|\leq C_n$ in the operator norm and $C_n\to 0$, then $f_n\to 0$ in the norm topology on $H^{-1}(\Omega)$, so every subsequence also converges to $0$. This is definitely overkill, but it satisfies the definition of "precompact."

Comment: You are right, it looks like it's overkill.

What if we just have $\left| f_n(\phi) \right| \to 0$, without having the bound in the operator norm, would that still satisfy the definition?

Comment: This is convergence in the weak$^*$ topology on $H^{-1}(\Omega)$. As $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, we choose an orthonormal basis $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$. We then choose $f_n(e_k) = \delta_{nk}$ (Kronecker delta), so $\lvert f_n(\phi)\rvert\to 0$ for all $\phi$, but $\|f_n\| = 1$ for all $n$. Therefore, $\lvert f_n(\phi)\rvert\to 0$ for all $\phi$ does not imply that there exists a subsequence that converges to $0$ in the norm topology.

Comment: I've never seen such a definition, it doesn't seem right (the sequence of real numbers $0,1,0,2,0,3,\ldots$ would be precompact according to this definition). I would say that a sequence is precompact iff the set of its coefficients is precompact. Equivalently, if every subsequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Yes there was something missing in the definition, the sequence in Evans' definition needs to be bounded. I forgot that important detail.